# Masonry does not float correctly - Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**The Scenario**

The site is built with Bootstrap, and has several div's (or columns) with a variation in height. Therefor I need to include Masonry to make them float/align correctly.

On the page below you can see 3 parts constructed different. The first one is not made with Masonry. And this part works perfect. Except that if one of the columns has a lot of text it floats wrong. This happends in *responsive view*.

The second and third is constructed with Masonry. I can't figure out where I am wrong, but none of them works correctly in responsive view. Actually both are very wrong, and not responsive at all.

Not sure where to begin. Any ideas?

Masonry is included in noconflict so it does not conflict with any JS.

**PHP**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><h1><!-- Info --></h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="masonry-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <!-- Info -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <!-- Info -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <!-- Info -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <!-- Info -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Masonry included in the footer:**

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 $('.masonry-container').imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('.masonry-container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true,
        isFitWidth: true
    });
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.masonry-container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true
    }, 'reload');
 });
});
</script>
```

Page can be found [here](http://higraf.no/).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a problem with one of the *js-files*. The javascript that made the columns fade in and out with animation interfered with the Masonry.

The problem was solved using `.visible-xs-block` and `.visible-sm-block` instead, so that the columns came on the same line.